# How to avoid having to declare type parameters for all dependencies in generic class

Tags: java, oop, generics, abstract-class

I have some question on the following problem. Can someone help?

The question is:

1. Is the following design a good design?
2. If yes, how to improve it to make it avoid declaring the type parameters at the entry class.

**Problem**

Assuming I am working on classes to handle request and fetch data for the response. I have

- request handler - which calls query helper to fetch the data
- query helper - calls query builder to build query and call the database with it
- query builder - builds the query.

In my case, each different request requires a different return type. The query helper also return different type for different request. In this context, I design it with generic class and abstract class.

```
abstract class RequestHandler<T1, T2> {
  QueryHelper<T2> helper;

  T1 doGet(Request request) {
    ...
    helper.callDatabase();
    return customLogic();
  }

  abstract T1 customLogic()
}

abstract class QueryHelper<T2> {
  QueryBuilder builder;

  T2 callDatabase() {
    ...
    client.call(builder.buildQuery());
    return customLogic(...);
  }

  abstract T2 customLogic()
}

abstract class QueryBuilder {

  abstract Query buildQuery();
}
```

With this design, I can handle different request with different subclass. e.g. For get product A request, I have

```
class ProductAQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder {
  
  @Override
  Query buildQuery() {
    ...
  }
}

class ProductAQueryHelper extends QueryHelper<TypeA> {
  QueryBuilder builder;

  ProductAQueryHelper(ProductAQueryBuilder builder) {
    this.builder = builder;
  }

  @Override
  TypeA customLogic()
}

class ProductARequestHandler extends RequestHandler<TypeB, TypeA> {
  QueryHelper<TypeA> helper;

  ProductARequestHandler(ProductAQueryHelper helper) {
    this.helper = helper;
  }
  
  @Override
  TypeB customLogic()
}
```

This seems fine because I simplified the problem. In reality,  I have more than one type parameter for RequestHandler and QueryBuilder, which makes me have to declare a lot of type parameters at RequestHandler<T1, T2, T3, T4...>. This is bothering me because I have to declare all type parameters for along the dependencies chain. Is there a way to improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the types T1, T2, T3, T4, ... really independent? Or can e.g. T3 be expressed as Collection<T1>? Your RequestHandler example indicates that T1 and T2 might have a strong correlation.

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks for the comment!

T1, T2, T3, T3 really independent - thanks for reminding me of that. I will see if I can reduce some of these. 

Just want to check quickly (I am not very experienced in OOD), is this type of design a solid pattern? or shall I look for alternative option?